# In CoreNLP what is the different between the default generated dependency trees?

Tags: stanford-nlp

Using Stanford CoreNLP, I generate dependency trees using default annotators. I view the XML output with the [XSLT transformation](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CoreNLP-to-HTML.xsl) provided on the project's website. I see three dependency tree categories each very similar, and they are:

- Uncollapsed dependencies
- Collapsed dependencies
- Collapsed dependencies with CC processed

See an example - http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/example.xml. I am wondering if anyone has experience with this project and knows the difference between each type of tree? Also, what is CC in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See section 4 of the Stanford Dependencies manual: [*Different styles of dependency representation*](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf#page=12). The first three subsections map to basic, collapsed, and CC-processed dependency representations, respectively.

Comment: Thanks! I wondered if a team member would be the one to pick up this question. I appreciate your assist - good luck at Standford and keep up the good work. I'm impressed by this software.